# How to draw a circle top-down in a tree

Tags: forest

How could I draw a circle top down in a tree? I need to draw a circle from PartP down to # only.
Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, twoside]{report}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[PartP
[Part]
[$\pi$
[$\pi$]
[PlP
[Pl]
[\#P
[\#]
[TP
[T]
[IndP
[Ind]
[MoodP
[Mood]
[AspP
[Asp]
[ResP
[Res]
[ProcP [Proc] [State]]
]
]
]
]
]
]
]
]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can name the relevant nodes and then use the `fitting` library (loaded automatically by `forest`) to draw the circle:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, twoside]{report}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[PartP,name=PartP,tikz={\node[draw,circle,fit=(PartP) (NumP)] {};}
[Part]
[$\pi$
[$\pi$]
[PlP
[Pl]
[\#P,name=NumP
[\#]
[TP
[T]
[IndP
[Ind]
[MoodP
[Mood]
[AspP
[Asp]
[ResP
[Res]
[ProcP [Proc] [State]]
]
]
]
]
]
]
]
]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]